# Save the world from Dr. Mysterious

Tags: cipher

## My name is ?????

You must find out Dr. Mysterious's name, which is your greatest weapon against him (it gives you power over him). His slave, Mr. Useless, has sent you some information but it is encrypted to prevent it from falling into the wrong hands. You must decrypt this information or the world will be destroyed by Dr. Mysterious's Amazing Technicolour Bomb, which only he can deactivate!

> `---BEGIN MESSAGE---`
>
> **PART 1**
>
> These are cryptic clues to Part 2:
>
> - NOOOO! I can't get back on track!
> - Newsflash: The waves on Cryptic Beach have reached 5 characters in height!
>
> **PART 2**
>
> `Tf 3h ot322eyrr 11 e ai 46kps7`
>
> **PART 3**
>
> When the numbers become letters, it's simple as Blaise de Vigenère!
>
> Remember, *YOU MUST FIND HIS NAME*
>
> `wpcik://die.bgapgzv.mck/fzlyq?a=XqJGYSt1WVJ` *That URL came out great, didn't it!*
>
> `---END MESSAGE---`

Comment: Part 3 is _obviously_ a youtube URL.

Comment: @JoeZ. `die.bgapgzv.mck` - the new name for YouTube!

Comment: Can you tell me does the youtube URL end with `dx1ncr` ?

Answer (score 6):

Dr. Mysterious name is:

> Jeff
>  Without repeating work from the previous answers, per part 1 and part 2, we have "The key for part 3 is 12321476."
>  The fact that the clues mention Vigenere, but have a numeric key suggests a Gronsfeld cipher. The URL obtained from this is gibberish though. Using Gronsfeld with a keyed alphabet, however, reveals the answer; the alphabet key is YOUMUSTFINDHISNAME (which reduces down to YOUMSTFINDHAE once you removed duplicate letters). Using this in conjunction with the numeric key gives us a URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfIOBLr1NDU . The title of this video is "My Name is Jeff"

Many thanks to Illyasviel for the work on Part 1 and 2!

Comment: Finally hahaha I was afraid this one would never be answered, OP went AWOL lol

Answer (score 5):

**Part 1**

1. > We are using a railfence cipher
2. > We have 5 rails

**Part 2**

Decoding using cipher from part 1 gives

> The key for part 3 is 12321476

Comment: Nice work so far, only **Part 3** left!

Comment: PWJTSHMIDSGWMYRKOYJZSWJF

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw That key doesn't make much sense to me. Are you sure that it's a youtube url?

Comment: That was my first thought too, it must not be a youtube url, but then I realized even just reverse encrypting the https:// at the start gave me a key that went like pwjts wether or not it was youtube, the pwjts still didnt make sense. I don't know what he means by "when numbers become letters", I tried converting them like this a=0, b=1, c=2, no luck. Then I thought he meant when the numbers in part 2 were replaced with letters but that was nonsense. I tried converting to words (e.g. twelve million etc) still didnt work, roman numerals, nope. Perhaps is Vigenere chart uses lower&upper case